# SQL LEFT JOIN to one new row

Tags: mysql, sql, h2

I have two tables
First, NAMES, has ID, NAME, ACTIV
Second, ALT, has ID, NAMEID, NAME

Now i LEFT JOIN the second colum to get the alt names for the activ names from the first table

```
SELECT m.NAME, a.NAME FROM NAMES M LEFT JOIN ALT A ON M.ID = A.NAMEID  WHERE m.ACTIV
```

the result ist

```
NAME                NAME  
User1               User1Altname1
User1               User1Altname2
User2               null
```

What i'm looking for is this

```
NAME
User1
User1Altname1
User1Altname2
User2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the ordering is important:

```
SELECT altname
FROM ((SELECT m.NAME, a.NAME as altname, 1 as isalt
       FROM NAMES M JOIN
            ALT A
            ON M.ID = A.NAMEID 
       WHERE m.ACTIV
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT m.NAME, m.NAME, 0
       FROM NAMES m
       WHERE m.ACTIV
      )
     ) n
ORDER BY name, isalt;
```

The idea is that you need `union all` to get the names and alternative names in one subquery.  The rest is just the `order by`.  Actually, the subquery is only necessary if you don't want the extra columns.

Comment: okay, thx, that is working, but i still get the null. this will took some time for me to understand, pen and paper i'm coming :)

Comment: @Garog . . . I think that's because the `left join` should just be `join`.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: you are good, and very fast. that solved the null problem but ignores now the m.ACTIV

Comment: got it, the WHERE m.ACTIV, needs to be in the third SELECT after the FROM NAMES m :)

Comment: @Garog . . . I put it in both subqueries.